# Excel VBA: Repeatedly Add Outside Borders

Tags: vba, excel, border

I need to add outside borders to some ranges in multiple worksheets, so I have written the following test code (which works):

```
Sub TestFun()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks("TestBook.xlsm")

    wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B2:D10").Select
    AddOutsideBorders

    wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2:D10").Select
    AddOutsideBorders

    wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("B2:D10").Select
    AddOutsideBorders

End Sub

Sub AddOutsideBorders()
    With Selection
      .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End Sub
```

However, my real workbook contains many more sheets and I need to perform more complicated tasks. So the question is, **how do I add borders without selecting a range first**? For example I want something as neat as this (it doesn't work):

```
Sub TestFun()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks("TestBook.xlsm")

    wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D10").AddOutsideBorders
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:D10").AddOutsideBorders
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:D10").AddOutsideBorders

End Sub

Sub AddOutsideBorders(rng As Range)
    With rng
      .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
      .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End Sub
```

More generally, how do i call another function defined on a range within a sub?

Comment: You can store the Sheets names in an Array. Also, do you always have to select the same range in each Worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you attempted is almost valid (and good on you for trying to avoid select), you just called the procedure in an incorrect way.  Instead, it should be called as:

```
Call AddOutsideBorders(wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D10"))
Call AddOutsideBorders(wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:D10"))
Call AddOutsideBorders(wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:D10"))
```

Comment: Happy to help.  Worth noting:  If you need to specify which `AddOutsideBorders(...)` routine is called if you have multiple versions in different Modules, just include the specific module beforehand ie. `Module1.AddOutsideBorders(...)`

Comment: Although I don't need this for my current project, I can see it's probably a better practice especially when you have 10 modules and 100 functions.  I'll probably go with the way you suggested.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Turn AddOutsideBorders into a function like this:

```
Sub TestFunc()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("TestBook.xlsm")

    AddOutsideBorders wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D10")
    AddOutsideBorders wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:D10")
    AddOutsideBorders wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:D10")
End Sub

Public Function AddOutsideBorders(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This also works.  So within 10 minutes I learnt two methods to call a function within a sub...

Comment: I'm sorry it seems I can't give both of you credit so I'll just go with the one that came first..  Thanks a lot nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

It also turns out that there's a range method to do what your AddOutsideBorders sub does (and eliminates having to specify each of the 4 outside borders) - the .BorderAround method.  In this case, you would implement with:

```
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D10").BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
```

You can simultaneously set other parameters, as well.  [Here's the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.borderaround) at Microsoft docs.